# DocuSign REST API - can't control Document Visibility on Envelopes from Documents?

Tags: docusignapi

The Docusign REST API describes a way to control document visibility when creating envelopes from documents:

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/

The option is `enforceSignerVisibility`.  However when I attempt to use this option, the visibility is NOT limited.  Am I doing something wrong?

I am using a modified version of the PHP DocuSign helper library (some features/options added).

Here is a test case I created.  In this case, there are two signers and two documents.  Signer 1 has a signature on Document 1 and Signer 2 has a signature on Document 2.  The goal is that Signer 1 would only see Document 1 and Signer 2 would only see Document 2.  However, the below example results in both signers seeing both documents:

**Code**

```
<?php

$client = new DocuSign_Client;
$service = new DocuSign_RequestSignatureService($client);

$documents = array( 
  new DocuSign_Document(
    "TestDoc1", 
    1,
    file_get_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sandbox/ncg/test1.pdf' ) 
  ), 
  new DocuSign_Document(
    "TestDoc2", 
    2,
    file_get_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sandbox/ncg/test2.pdf' ) 
  ) 
);

$signer1 = new DocuSign_Recipient( 
  1, 
  1, 
  "Signer 1", 
  "test.tfcornerstone+t1@gmail.com",
  NULL
);

$signer1->setTab("signHereTabs",array(
  "anchorYOffset" => "0",
  "anchorXOffset" => "0",
  "anchorString" => "[__[Signer1]__]",
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" => true,
) );


$signer2 = new DocuSign_Recipient( 
  1, 
  2, 
  "Signer 2", 
  "test.tfcornerstone+t2@gmail.com",
  NULL
);

$signer2->setTab("signHereTabs",array(
  "anchorYOffset" => "0",
  "anchorXOffset" => "0",
  "anchorString" => "[__[Signer2]__]",
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" => true,
) );

$recipients = array( $signer1, $signer2 );
$emailSubject = "Test Doc";
$emailBlurb = "Testing Visibility"; 
$status = 'sent'; // can be "created" or "sent"
$eventNotifications = new DocuSign_EventNotification(
  $url, //url
  false, //loggingEnabled
  false, //requireAcknowledgment,
  false, //useSoapInterface,
  NULL, //soapNameSpace,
  false, //includeCertificateWithSoap,
  false, //signMessageWithX509Cert,
  false, //includeDocuments,
  false, //includeTimeZone,
  false, //includeSenderAccountAsCustomField,
  NULL, //envelopeEvents,
  array( "Completed", "Sent" ) //recipientEvents 
);

$options = array(
  "enforceSignerVisibility" => true,
);

$response = $service->signature->createEnvelopeFromDocument( 
  $emailSubject,
  $emailBlurb,
  $status,
  $documents,                                                                
  $recipients,
  $eventNotifications,
  $options
);

d($response);
```

**CURL request**

Url: https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXX/envelopes

Method: POST

Headers:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{"emailSubject":"Test Doc","emailBlurb":"Testing Visibility","documents":[{"name":"TestDoc1","documentId":1},{"name":"TestDoc2","documentId":2}],"status":"sent","enforceSignerVisibility":true,"recipients":{"signers":[{"routingOrder":1,"recipientId":1,"name":"Signer 1","email":"test.tfcornerstone+t1@gmail.com","clientUserId":null,"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorYOffset":"0","anchorXOffset":"0","anchorString":"[__[Signer1]__]","anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true}]},"embeddedRecipientStartUrl":null,"excludedDocuments":null},{"routingOrder":1,"recipientId":2,"name":"Signer 2","email":"test.tfcornerstone+t2@gmail.com","clientUserId":null,"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorYOffset":"0","anchorXOffset":"0","anchorString":"[__[Signer2]__]","anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true}]},"embeddedRecipientStartUrl":null,"excludedDocuments":null}]},"eventNotification":{"loggingEnabled":false,"requireAcknowledgment":false,"useSoapInterface":false,"includeCertificateWithSoap":false,"signMessageWithX509Cert":false,"includeDocuments":false,"includeTimeZone":false,"includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":false,"recipientEvents":[{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Completed"},{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Sent"}]}}
<<PDF CONTENT>>--myboundary--
```

**Formatted JSON data**

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Test Doc",
  "emailBlurb": "Testing Visibility",
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "TestDoc1",
      "documentId": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "TestDoc2",
      "documentId": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "enforceSignerVisibility": true,
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "recipientId": 1,
        "name": "Signer 1",
        "email": "test.tfcornerstone+t1@gmail.com",
        "clientUserId": null,
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "anchorXOffset": "0",
              "anchorString": "[__[Signer1]__]",
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "embeddedRecipientStartUrl": null,
        "excludedDocuments": null
      },
      {
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "recipientId": 2,
        "name": "Signer 2",
        "email": "test.tfcornerstone+t2@gmail.com",
        "clientUserId": null,
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "anchorXOffset": "0",
              "anchorString": "[__[Signer2]__]",
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "embeddedRecipientStartUrl": null,
        "excludedDocuments": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "eventNotification": {
    "loggingEnabled": false,
    "requireAcknowledgment": false,
    "useSoapInterface": false,
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": false,
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": false,
    "includeDocuments": false,
    "includeTimeZone": false,
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": false,
    "recipientEvents": [
      {
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe DocVis can be set to "Off" in order to enforce it in the API. In Preferences -> Features change the DocVis dropdown to "Sender Can Set Must Sign To View Unless Sender Account" and give the same request another shot.